# HTML - constant headers/auto updating headers?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible in HTML to create a constant header? e.g. a header that you only write in one file and goes out to all the sub webpages on the website instead of having to update like 200 webpages if you want to change the header?

Comment: Not possible with HTML. You could either use [HAML](http://haml.info/) /[Liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid) (or any other template engines) or Server-side programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

Not with purely html no,

However with a little php you could.

Create a `Header.php` and put your header code in there.

each of your `.html` files becomes a `.php`

so you can then do

```
<?php include('Header.php'); ?>
```

Now any time you change Header.php every page gets the change.

**Note:** If your running this locally you will need a local "server" to run php, I personally use [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)